# Adding values to PHP array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

That's what I have: `<a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a>`. `<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>` - it's an array, which contains some links. I need to add an extra hashtag parameter `#nav-link` to the end of each link. That's how I tried do it, but this code doesn't work:

```
<a id="likeLink" href=""><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#likeLink").attr("href", <?=$arItem["LINK"]?> + "#nav-link");
    });
</script>
```

I don't know PHP quite well, but I think I need to add new array and return there all necessary links with hashtag and use this array in `href`.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Note sure it helps but I think it should be $("#likeLink").attr("href", "<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>#nav-link");

Comment: Is this code in a loop in php?

Comment: @nicolas Unfortunately the result is the same, after second click I get only last element of the array

Comment: @Sean Yes, but it works well in this variant `<a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a>`

Comment: It sounds like you might have an `id` issue. `id`s are supposed to be UNIQUE, so if this is in a loop you will have `n` number of `id="likeLink"`. jQuery/javascript will not know which `$("#likeLink")` you are linking to.

Comment: @Sean You might be right, I remembered I had the same problem in c# code, I think it can solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give your php to javascript into a javascript string:

`$("#likeLink").attr("href", "<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>#nav-link");`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing more but it looks like you need quotes around the link on this line:

```
$("#likeLink").attr("href", "<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>" + "#nav-link");
```

Comment: Unfortunately the result is the same, after second click I get only last element of the array

Comment: Does it work if you just put the code in PHP?
$("#likeLink").attr("href", "<?php echo $arItem["LINK"].'#nav-link'; ?>");

Comment: There's no reason it would be any different. I'm just curious if there's some code we can't see that's causing the issue.

Comment: I'm sure there are guys here hefty enough to fix bugs in code that they can't see :)